# Performance problems when plotting spectrogram

Tags: performance, matlab, plot, gnuplot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a spectrogram - for the purposes of this question it could be rephrased as **I am trying to plot a large matrix** (ca. 40 000x3000 double, reals). The graphic output is (based on my experience) the biggest issue of matlab `spectrogram` function and naturally I have encountered the same issue during designing my own spectrogram script. Using `surface` I sometimes got so jammed that a restart of the computer was needed.

**I have tried:**

- adding `'LineStyle', 'None'` to the `surface` and it actually really helped but not enough.
- moving the whole problem to Octave and GNUplot which I thought to be more lightweighted. Without any particular succes, but I am not a pro in using gnuplot - there might be something I overlooked. I have tried just the `surface`.
- *not tested idea:* Would it be helpful not to let the matlab/gnuplot plot the figure of challenging size but save it as an image in crazy resolution to be studied in some image viewer (and therefore bypass redrawing of the figure, which is the core of the problem)? If you think so, could you share a code?

If you have any hints, I would be grateful. The goal is to to have figure with good resolution, still readible as a spectrogram (so no `mesh` etc., please).

**Note:** I am aware of the possibility to plot the matrix by parts, which would of course help. *I am trying to find another solution, possibly better suited function, procedure etc.*

**Update:** Code to be copied, pasted, corrected etc.:

```
data=rand(48000,2000)
surface(data,'LineStyle','None','Visible','off')
xlabel('time');
ylabel('frequency');
colorbar('eastoutside');
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters');
saveas(gcf,'specgram.pdf');
```

Comment: At which particular point you get the performance issues? Displaying in the figure window or saving to a file?

Comment: Displaying is bad, working with displayed is horrible (zooming, shifting the view and so on.)

Comment: have you tried to save it as a vector graphic (`'renderer','painters'`) without displaying it (`'Visible','off'`)? Can you provide a minimal example for copy&paste with maybe random data?

Comment: Average the matrix in blocks and display the resulting smaller matrix? 40000x3000 pixels won't be visible on the screen anyway

Comment: A surface is expensive, since it consists of many 3d-objects (even if they happen to lie in a plane). If you just want a heatmap, using `imagesc` is much more efficient. Also what Luis Mendo said: downscale your spectrogram to a size more appropriate for screen display.

Comment: @Luis Mendo : The goal is to have figure still good enough to be largely mangified, so that's not the way. @A. Donda : That would be possible, but using `imagesc` I can't set the proper axes titles etc., if I am not wrong. @ thewaywewalk : That seems good, I am updating the example in a second.

Comment: @VictorPira, you can customize an `imagesc` plot just as much as you can a `surf` plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK, let me sum the experiments done with previous comments and answer to close this question.**

### Saving as vector graphics (thewaywewalked)

i.e. don't let MATLAB to view the plot but save as a vector graphics it to be viewed outside the MATLAB.

```
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters');
saveas(gcf,'spectgr.pdf');
```

#### Advantages

You draw the data only once and the there are still available.

#### Disadvantages

Produced files are still bloody big and working with them is not very efficient.

**This is not a good way to go.**

### Using imagesc (A. Donda)

Don't let MATLAB compute 3-D elements in `surf` and use `imagesc` instead.

#### Advantages

Very efficient, unbelievably fast compared to `surf`.

#### Disadvantages

You need to spend a little more time to make it look like spectrogram (e.g. axes are inverted).

**That is the best solution for me, thank you very, very much! Combined with saving as vector graphics it produces reasonably small files, still very well able to be zoomed.**

### Down-sampling (Luis Mendo & Yair Altman)

This is something I generally didn't want to do, because I need good resolution of the data. I can imagine writing something like zooming-algorithm which chooses the size of the block depending on area to be displayed but it seems overthinked.
 However, the reduce_plot function is interesting and maybe there will be a suitable place for it in the future. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The biggest performance boost would be achieved by down-sampling the displayed data. After all, you don't really have nearly enough pixels on your screen to display all the data. There are various ways this down-sampling can be done. If you don't need to worry about zooming in/out, then you could simply modify your input data (e.g., by block-averaging, or by selecting every Nth data element). But then if you zoom in on the plotted data you won't see all the data.

If you need to support zooming/panning while still displaying downsampled data, a good place to start would be the [reduce_plot function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40790-plot--big) on the Matlab File Exchange. You should be able to relatively easily adapt it to work with your plot type (I think it currently only works with simple line plots). A visualization of the benefits of reduce_plot (and down-sampling in general) can be found in [the blog post that highlighted reduce_plot](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2013/06/07/plot-real-big/) as File Exchange "Pick-of-the-Week".

reduce_plot, as well as numerous other Matlab performance tips, are described in my recent book "***[Accelerating MATLAB Performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/books/matlab-performance)***" (CRC Press 2014).